# Firestore timestamp not including current date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Problem:I have a collection called Events and an event document has dateStart field. What I want to do is get the documents with dateStart >= to current_date which is May 1 in my timezone. When I use the query below it doesn't include May 1 and only gets beyond May 1.

```
const eventsQuery = npmMod.query(
      npmMod.collection(db, "events"),
      npmMod.where("dateStart", ">=", new Date()),
      npmMod.orderBy("dateStart"),
      npmMod.limit(5)
);
```

Below is my sample event document with dateStart set to  May 1, 2023 at 00:00:00(12:00:00 AM UTC+8 in my timezone)

[image: Event Document]

I tried replicating the query in firebase console and the results are the same. It is also resulting to 3 documents and not including the documents with dateStart of May 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new Date()` will have both current date and time, You can verify that using `console.log(new Date());`

Instead you should query with `May 1, 2023` midnight as follows :

```js
const now = new Date();
const midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
console.log(midnight); // Will get your desired date

const eventsQuery = query(
  collection(db, "events"),
  where("dateStart", ">=", midnight),
  orderBy("dateStart"),
  limit(5)
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(eventsQuery);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

**Note** : I have used Firebase V9 modular approach here from [**Get multiple documents from a collection**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Here `now` will have a current date and time where `midnight` will  represent the same date with the time set to midnight.